# How do I suggest a merge of tags on a Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

For example, on Stack Overflow there are two tags for Application Insights, `ms-application-insights` and `az-application-insights`.

I'm guessing this is originally to distinguish **Application Insights** on Azure, as opposed to other environments.

However, I think the two tags are synonymous. If a question is about Application Insights, it would seldom be Azure-specific.

If you're interested in Application Insights questions you'd essentially have to follow both tags, even though they're essentially about the same thing.

And if the question is specifically about Azure, wouldn't one just use both the `azure` and the `ms-application-insights` tags? Or is the general idea to instead have additional composite tags, or perhaps create synonyms?

Anyway, the core of my question is: **how do you suggest a tag merge on a Stack Exchange site?**

Comment: Perhaps I just need higher rep on SO to do it under http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge?

Comment: In the meantime, you could also bring this up on meta.SO. Maybe sufficiently privileged users will agree, or maybe there's a good reason to keep these tags separate.

Comment: @Ted I agree with Arthur. Bringing it on the meta is the best option you got. Dealing with tags is one of the normal uses of meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try asking on the correct meta site (e.g. if it's SO, ask on Meta SO).

Of course, you don't have enough rep to create tag synonyms so try asking to merge the two "duplicate" tags. Those who can merge these tags might agree with your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and merge them / make them synonyms. If they don't agree, they might not allow them to be merged. Everyone will have their reasoning, but sooner or later the tags will be merged or deemed unable to merge. So the best thing you can do now until you gain the correct privilege is to ask to merge the two tags on the meta site.